# styling accordeon with +\-

Tags: html, css, accordion

I'm just learning coding and im trying to make accordion panel with +/-. [Here](http://fiddle.jshell.net/5z5885bp/) is my html and css. And what my [goal](http://oi57.tinypic.com/28thmid.jpg)
What with +/-? just can't seem to make it work in css (no jquery no javascript if it possible). Thank you

Comment: Hi, check it here: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Khumesh/te3pfcc9/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
.accordion input:checked + label:before {
    content: '-';
}
.accordion input:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content: '+';
}
```

Try using the :before selector to add + or - before the label text. Then you just have to style the element e.g. like this

```
.accordion label {
    padding-left: 50px;
}
.accordion input:checked + label:before {
    content: '-';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 42px;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
.accordion input:not(:checked) + label:before {
    content: '+';
    display: inline-block;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    line-height: 42px;
    width: 10px;
    padding: 0 15px;
    height: 100%;
    border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
    text-align: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove ,  and  tags from html section in fiddle.

You can use code from fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/Khumesh/te3pfcc9/